# Is this the correct implementation of a recursive search function in a Linked List?

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, linked-list

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.next = None

class LinkedList:
  def __init__(self, head=None):
    self.head = head

  def insert(self, node):
    if not self.head:
      self.head = node
    else:
      node.next = self.head
      self.head = node

  def search(self, node):
    if self.head == node:
      return self.head
    else:
      if self.head.next:
        self.head = self.head.next
        return self.search(node)
```

I have a feeling that that resetting the head to head.next isn't quite right. If it's not, how can my recursive function move to the next node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting head is definitely wrong, you'll lose your linked list this way.  For the first call to search you need to specify where to start and then what node to check next (if you have any):

```
def search(self, node, next_node=None):
   if next_node is None:
       next_node = self.head
   if next_node == node:
       return next_node
   elif next_node.next is None:
       return None
   else:
       return self.search(node, next_node.next)
```

Comment: I'm not quite understanding how next_node is being passed to the else statement? Could you further explain that?

Comment: The second argument of the search method is the next node to examine, which is head.next, head.next.next, head.next.next, and so on.  When you call search from outside of the class next_node is none, which is a signal that you need to set it to head.  BTW, directly comparing nodes will likely not work, you need `if next_node.data == node.data: return next_node`

Comment: I should have added, in the first if block next_node effectively creates a new variable, but due to python scoping rules it's visible within body of the method.

Comment: So in the first if block, the next_node variable is created and then subsequently passed to the search function as an argument?

Comment: next_node is essentially created twice, first as an argument to the search method.  If value of this argument is None (on the very first call to search), than it's recreated with value of head.